# "Outstanding" but bad

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, vocabulary

[Outstanding](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/outstanding)

> 1. prominent; conspicuous; striking
> 2. marked by superiority or distinction; excellent; distinguished
> 3. standing out; projecting:

From what I have come across, this word is normally used in a positive connotation. To use it in a negative connotations, we attach negative words with it like "outstandingly bad", "outstandingly filthy" etc.

So my question is : *Is "outstanding" by itself always used in a positive connotation or are there exceptions to this?*

For Example:

> It was **outstanding** how Joe beat me up after I corrected his grammar. He is not an aggressive person at all.

Is the use of **outstanding** incorrect in the above sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**[outstanding](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/outstanding)**" is an *adjective*. The phrase "*adjective + ("how" clause)*" works with almost any adjective and is used to talk about an idea and your opinion about it. Some adjectives, however, sound ridiculous with this phrase *(like "**happy**" for instance)*. Yes, in your case you can use "**outstanding**" that way. This word can be a synonym of "**excellent**", "**exceptional**", "**terrific**", "**amazing**", "**remarkable**" and many others.

- [**How Joe beat me up**] (*after I corrected his grammar*) was [**outstanding**].

You can also use the *adverb* - "**[outstandingly](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/outstandingly)**" but for that you'll have to rephrase your sentence:

- I was outstandingly well beaten up by Joe after I corrected his grammar. *(Passive)*
- Joe beat me up outstandingly well after I corrected his grammar. *(Active)*